# VBA Dynamically Building A Formula From An Array

Tags: excel, vba, automation, excel-2010

I am trying to dynamically construct a formula based on an array that I have generated from a cell (separated by commas), as there is a varying amount of elements in the array I need to append a new "formula block" with the updated element to use in a if statement that is generated after the for each loop. VBA is throwing a type mismatch error in the `InvestigateFormula =` line, here is my code:

```
For Each Type In ToIgnore()
    InvestigateFormula = "(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(*" & ToIgnore(Type) & "*," & _
        AssetTypesCol & "2)),"
    FullFormula = InvestigateFormula & FullFormula
Next Asset
    FinalInvestigateFormula = "=IF(OR" & FullFormula & "),""Ignore"", """")"
ActiveCell.Formula = FinalInvestigateFormula
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way of doing this or how I might be able to correct the above code. Btw I am not declaring a variant I am simply declaring `ToIgnore()` as String and using the split function from the variable which contains the comma separated values to generate the array/items to loop over.

Comment: your string ends with an extra comma.  You will need to remove the ending `,` from your `FullFormula` after the loop.

Comment: It would be simpler (and a lot shorter) to use a `COUNT(SEARCH(` formula (no wildcards necessary BTW) with an array of text items, or put the array into a range of cells and use `SUM(COUNTIF(` with the search cell as the first argument and the range of cells as the second.

Comment: @Rory I am using this to generate a formula that allows me to ignore certain rows based on if the value is in the specified col, how would I write out this formula to do so ? I'm actually modifying an existing macro that I had used prior where this formula was working correctly but now there are more requirements that need me to add this dynamic list to exclude values.

Comment: Something like: `FinalInvestigateFormula = "=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({""" & Join(ToIgnore, """,""") & """}," & AssetTypesCol & "2)),""Ignore"", """")"`

Comment: @Rory Thanks a lot that accomplished what I needed to do, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Type" is a reserved name? Try strType instead?